# Huffman Decoding Compressed File

Tags: c++, data-structures, visual-studio-2017, huffman-code

I have a program that produces a Huffman tree based on ASCII character frequency read in a text input file. The Huffman codes are stored in a string array of 256 elements, empty string if the character is not read. This program also encodes and compresses an output file.

I am now trying to decompress and decode my current output file which is opened as an input file and a new output file is to have the decoded message identical to the original text input file.

My thought process for this part of my assignment is to work backwards from the encoding function I have made and read 8 bits at a time and somehow decode the message by updating a variable (string n) which is an empty string at first, through recursion of the Huffman tree until I get a code to output to output file.

I have currently started the function but I am stuck and I am looking for some guidance in writing my current decodeOutput function. All help is appreciated.
My completed encodedOutput function and decodeOutput function is down below:

(For encodedOutput function, fileName is the input file parameter, fileName2 is the output file parameter)

(For decodeOutput function, fileName2 is the input file parameter, fileName 3 is output file parameter)

code[256] is a parameter for both of these functions and holds the Huffman code for each unique character read in the original input file, for example, the character 'H' being read in the input file may have a code of "111" stored in the code array for code[72] at the time it is being passed to the functions.

```
void encodeOutput(const string & fileName, const string & fileName2, string code[256]) {
    ifstream ifile;//to read file
    ifile.open(fileName, ios::binary);
    if (!ifile) //to check if file is open or not
    {
        die("Can't read again");
    }
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(fileName2, ios::binary);
    if (!ofile) {
        die("Can't open encoding output file");
    }
    int read;
    read = ifile.get();//read one char from file and store it in int
    char buffer = 0, bit_count = 0;
    while (read != -1) {
        for (unsigned b = 0; b < code[read].size(); b++) { // loop through bits (code[read] outputs huffman code)
            buffer <<= 1;
            buffer |= code[read][b] != '0'; 
            bit_count++;
            if (bit_count == 8) {
                ofile << buffer;
                buffer = 0;
                bit_count = 0;
            }
        }
        read = ifile.get();
    }

    if (bit_count != 0)
        ofile << (buffer << (8 - bit_count));

    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
}

//Work in progress
void decodeOutput(const string & fileName2, const string & fileName3, string code[256]) {
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(fileName2, ios::binary);
    if (!ifile)
    {
        die("Can't read again");
    }
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open(fileName3, ios::binary);
    if (!ofile) {
        die("Can't open encoding output file");
    }
    string n = ""; 
    for (int c; (c = ifile.get()) != EOF;) {
        for (unsigned p = 8; p--;) {
            if ((c >> p & 1) == '0') { // if bit is a 0

            }
            else if ((c >> p & 1) == '1') { // if bit is a 1

            }
            else { // Output string n (decoded character) to output file
              ofile << n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to put your huffman codes into a tree, then use the bits you read to traverse the tree

Comment: whats  in the parameter  "code", give some example

Comment: code[256] is a parameter for both of these functions and holds the huffman code for each unique character read in the original input file, for example the character 'H' being read in the input file may have a code of "111" stored in the code array for code[72] at the time it is being passed to the functions.

Comment: How do you construct the huffman code if you don't have access to the original file? Are you saving it separately?

Comment: Yes, you  need to build a tree to decode

Comment: You must have built a tree to generate the Huff codes in the first place? You can use the same tree for decoding

Comment: That is the part I am currently confused in, how would I use the bits I read to traverse the tree?

Comment: Read a zero go left, read a one go right. When you reach a leaf output that character and go back to the root of the tree

Answer (score 0):

The decoding would be easier if you had the original Hoffman tree used to construct the codebook. But suppose you only have the codebook (i.e., the `string code[256]`) but not the original Hoffman tree. What you can do is the following:

- Partition the codebook into groups of codewords with different lengths. Say the codebook consists of codewords with n different lengths: L<sub>0</sub> < L<sub>1</sub> < ... < L<sub>n-1</sub> .
- Read (but do not consume yet) k bits from input file, with k increasing From L<sub>0</sub> up to L<sub>n-1</sub>, until you find a match between the input k bits and a codeword of length k = L<sub>i</sub> for some i.
- Output the 8-bit character corresponding to the matching codeword, and consume the k bits from input file.
- Repeat until all bits from input file are consumed.

If the codebook were constructed correctly, and you always look up the codewords in increasing length, you should never find a sequence of input bits which you cannot find a matching codeword.

Effectively, in terms of the Hoffman tree equivalence, every time you compare k input bits with a group of codewords of length k, you are checking whether a leaf at tree level-k contains an input-matching codeword; every time you increase k to the next longer group of codewords, you are walking down the tree to a higher level (say level-0 is the root).

Comment: I am partially understanding the steps mentioned. Am I holding the code words in an array of its own and then looping over it while reading the bits?

Comment: There are various way to store the length-partitioned codewords. You could use a `map<int, set<int>>`, which maps every (valid) codeword length to a set of codeword indexes (which would be the codewords' respective byte values). Then, you would scan from the shortest length (the smallest key k of the `map`), read k bits from input file, and compare the k bits with the codewords in the `set` mapped from key k.